# Insert smart card issue while initializing keystore in java

Tags: java, security, applet, keystore

I' working around eToken using `Applet`. I'm initializing  key store using below code.

```
KeyStore keyStore = null;
try {        
     keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
     keyStore.load(null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Problem :**
I'm working with multiple eTokens. One of my eToken stores public key in system. So when I disconnect that eToken and try to use other eToken it shows "Insert smart card" [Check image] message while initializing the keystore. As that eToken not connected to my system. So if there is any other way to initialize keystore only for connected eTokens.

[image]

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Me too.  Did anyone find a solution? @Seephor? @Vicky Thakor?

Comment: Any solutions to this yet? It appears that all I have to do is press "cancel" for it to work properly.. (After I press "cancel" it won't prompt for password until it is required) @Amber